# Using awk to print the word on the second column of the second line of a file only if it ends in `.local`?

Tags: awk

I'd like to print the word on the second column of the second line of a file, only if it ends in `.local`.

How can I achieve this using `awk`?

Right now I have `awk 'FNR==2{print $2}'`, but this prints the word no matter what.

Comment: [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output. Make sure to include lines that must not change along with lines that must changes and cover all of the edge cases..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a check for $2 against RE:

```
awk 'FNR == 2 && $2 ~ /\.local$/ { print $2 }'
```